# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'docgenerator.curricula' doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I've seen similar questions to problem I have, but none of them really assisted me.

Below is the code:

**The controller** (The create and store methods)

```
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Curriculum;
use App\Company;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class CurriculumsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
        $curriculums = Curriculum::all();

        return view('curriculums.index',['curriculums' =>$curriculums]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
        //
        $companies = Company::where('comptype_id', '=', 1)->get();
        $users = DB::table('users');

        //dd($companies);
        return view('curriculums.create', ['companies'=>$companies,'users'=>$users]);
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //

            $curriculum = $request->validate([
                'curriculum_code' => 'required|unique:curriculums|max:10|min:9',
                'curriculum_title' => 'required',
            ]);


            $curriculum = Curriculum::create([
                'curriculum_code' => $request->input('curriculum_code'),


            ]);


            if ($curriculum) {
                return redirect()->route('curriculums.show', ['curriculums' => $curriculum->id])
                    ->with('success', 'Curriculum header created Successfully');
            }


        return back()->withInput()->with('error' , 'Curriculum header could not be created');
    }
```

**The Model**

```
class Curriculum extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = ['curriculum_code',
        'curriculum_title',
        'company_id',
        'user_id',
    ];

    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Company');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

**Blade**

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('curriculums.store')}}">
                         {{csrf_field()}}

                         <div class="box-body">
                             <div class="row">
                                 <div class="col-12">
                                     <div class="form-group {{$errors->has('curriculum_code') ? 'has-error': ''}}">
                                         <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Curriculum Code<span class="danger">*</span> </label>
                                         <div class="col-sm-10">
                                             <input class="form-control" name="curriculum_code" type="text" value="" id="example-text-input">
                                             @if($errors->has('curriculum_code'))
                                                 <span class="help-block">{{$errors->first('first')}}</span>
                                             @endif
                                         </div>
                                     </div>
                                     <div class="form-group {{$errors->has('curriculum_title') ? 'has-error': ''}}">
                                         <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Curriculum Title<span class="danger">*</span> </label>
                                         <div class="col-sm-10">
                                             <input class="form-control" name="curriculum_title" type="text" value="" id="example-text-input">
                                             @if($errors->has('curriculum_title'))
                                                 <span class="help-block">{{$errors->first('first')}}</span>
                                             @endif
                                         </div>
                                     </div>
                                    <div class="form-group ">
                                        <label for="company" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Development Quality Partner<span class="danger">*</span> </label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">

                                                <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;" name="company_id">
                                                   @foreach($companies as $company)
                                                      <option value="{{$company->id}}">{{$company->name}}</option>
                                                   @endforeach
                                                </select>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                             </div>
                             <div class="text-xs-right">
                                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit">Occupational Information</button>
                             </div>

                         </div>
                     </form>
```

I understand that the problem occurs in the controller when trying to insert data into the database.  The main reason I'm struggling so much with this is: The database doesn't contain any table called curricula, and neither does the controller contain the word curricula. I am new to laravel, so any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The table for the `Curriculum` should be called `curricula` because it's plural for `curriculum`.

If you're using a different name, do this in the model:

```
protected $table = 'custom_table_name';
```

Learn more about [Laravel naming conventions](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#follow-laravel-naming-conventions) in my best practices repo.

Answer (score 3):

if the table name is not the plural of the model name you should specify it in table variable like this.

add protected `$table = 'curricula';` like this to model

```
class Curriculum extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'curricula';
    //
    protected $fillable = ['curriculum_code',
        'curriculum_title',
        'company_id',
        'user_id',
    ];

    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Company');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```